# Permanent address of an EEA national and non- EEA national for EEA family permit application?

Tags: visas, uk

I am an Indian citizen living in Czech republic and my wife is an Croatian. We recently got married. We are in a relationship from past 2 years. I have article 10 residence card ( residence card of a family member of a EU citizen). I am planning to apply for EEA family permit in February 2nd week.

My wife moved to UK for finding a job and I will be moving to UK as soon as I complete my studies in Czech republic. I have few questions.

1. My wife moved to UK on 16th Jan 2019 and she is living in a hostel for temporary till I join her. Can I put that address as permanent address of EEA national in UK ?
2. We are also planning to book a Airbnb for a month and find a flat in UK after I move to UK. Can I put Airbnb address as a permanent address in UK for both us ?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you aware that with your Article 10 card you do not need an EEA family permit?

Comment: Yes, I am aware about that. But at the border there are chances of refusing my entry if I don't provide enough proofs. So I thought of not taking any risk and apply for EEA family permit.

Comment: And also I don't know  what will be the proof that I can work in UK if enter UK with article 10 residence card.

Comment: An EEA family permit does not serve as proof of employability in the UK.  You can ask about that on [Expatriates.SE], though you may want to look around a bit first because there are already a few questions and answers on that subject.

Comment: EEA family permit allows me to work. It is there on the website.

Comment: I have looked around a bit, but I am still not sure about what to put in permanent address in UK if we are booking airbnb for 1 month or a hotel.

Comment: What website?  The [government website](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit) says you need a residence card for that.  And your right to work itself stems not from the residence card nor the EEA family permit, but from the very fact that you are the spouse of an EU citizen established in the UK.

Comment: It's certainly reasonable to apply for an EEA family permit anyway, but you might want to consider that you might receive *less* scrutiny at the border.  For example, you probably won't be asked for your "permanent address in the UK"; they'll just ask you where your wife is living.

Comment: In the government website, it says EEA family permit allows me to work upto 6 months. After expiry of that I can apply for residence card which will be a proof that I can work in UK. These proofs I can show to the employer if I am eligible to work or not. If I am not wrong

Comment: I understand what you are saying. It will be easy if I just go with article residence card. What I am worried is that when I am applying for jobs in UK what proof can I give if I am eligible to work or not in UK?

Comment: The [list of documents an employer can use as a defense against hiring someone unauthorized to work](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/acceptable-right-to-work-documents-an-employers-guide) *does not include the EEA family permit.* As a matter of law, you are authorized to work because of your marriage, so an employer could hire you, but employers are likely to stick to the specified documents.  Can you link to the website you're referring to?  I don't see that at the one I linked to.  It doesn't say anything about the EEA family permit allowing you to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not mentioned in the government page. I was looking at some other immigration adviser pages.

Comment: If this is the case, then I will try to go to UK without EEA family permit.

Comment: Do you know if i can work right away when I move to UK without EEA family permit. As you know UK is leaving brexit and residence card will not be valid after 2020 I guess. They will be opening settlement scheme.

Comment: It might be that employers *do* actually give favorable consideration to the EEA FP; nothing says that they *cannot.* If immigration advice pages say that it can be useful, then you might want to investigate whether it is. I certainly don't want to discourage you from applying; I just want to make sure you don't go in with the expectation that employers will necessarily regard you as being authorized to work because you have an EEA family permit. You can in theory work immediately but in practice probably need a "certificate of application" (see link above and related Q's at [Expatriates.SE]).

Comment: I was researching on immigration pages for right to work on EEA permit. Nowhere says EEA family permit allows me to work. I am confused what to do now. Should I go to UK without EEA and apply for settlement scheme and show employers my right to work based on my marriage certificate?

Comment: "Should I go to UK without EEA and apply for settlement scheme and show employers my right to work based on my marriage certificate?" Perhaps, but the place to ask about that is [Expatriates.SE].  Such things are off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My wife moved to UK on 16th Jan 2019 and she is living in a hostel for temporary till I join her. Can I put that address as permanent address of EEA national in UK ?
>
> We are also planning to book a Airbnb for a month and find a flat in UK after I move to UK. Can I put Airbnb address as a permanent address in UK for both us ?

Either option is probably reasonable depending on when your wife is going to leave the hostel.  You might even put "none," since she does not yet have a permanent address.

Do be aware that if you arrive in the UK after she has been there for more than three months that you will need to show evidence that she is a "qualified person" (working, studying, self-sufficient, or, under some circumstances, looking for work).

Comment: Do I need to show that she is a qualified person if she is living ther for less than 3months when I arrive in UK ?

Comment: @Deepak no.  If she has not yet been in the UK for three months when you arrive then it is not necessary to establish that she is a qualified person, or even that she is likely to find work (some years ago the UK apparently refused FP applications on similar grounds, but courts put a stop to that).